# Spring Boot RestController inheritance and ambiguous mapping issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to implement inherited controllers for my Spring Boot Rest project. As you see in example code snippets, I have standard endpoints for all controllers at BaseTableController, but for some of the concrete controllers I need to override methods. When I implement it like that I get  `Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'clientRfmController' method` exception on startup.

```
public abstract class BaseTableController<T extends BaseTableModel> {  

@Override
    public BaseTableService<T> getService() {
        return (BaseTableService<T>) super.getService();
    }
   @GetMapping({
            PATH_GET,
            PATH_VIEW_GET}
    )
    public T getWithParam(@RequestParam UUID gid) {
        T t = null;
        if (gid != null) {
            t = getService().get(gid);
        }
        return getWithErrorCheck(t);
    }
}
```

-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(TBL_CLIENTRFM)
public class ClientRfmController extends BaseTableController<ClientRfmCommon> {
    @Override
    public ClientRfmService getService() {
        return (ClientRfmService) super.getService();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {PATH_GET, PATH_VIEW_GET})
    public List<ClientRfmCommon> getByAccid(Long accid, @RequestParam(required = false) UUID gid) {
        List<ClientRfmCommon> byAccid = null;
        if (gid != null) {
            byAccid = Collections.singletonList(super.getWithParam(gid));
        } else {
            byAccid = Collections.singletonList(getService().getByAccid(accid));
        }
        return byAccid;
    }


}
```

I've found a workaround by implementing custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping.

```
  @Configuration
    public class WebMvcRegistrationsConfig implements WebMvcRegistrations {

        @Override
        public OoRequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
            OoRequestMappingHandlerMapping ooRequestMappingHandlerMapping = new OoRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
            ooRequestMappingHandlerMapping.setOrder(0);
            return ooRequestMappingHandlerMapping;
        }


    }
```

-

```
public class OoRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

    @Override
    protected void registerHandlerMethod(Object handler, Method method, RequestMappingInfo mapping) {
        HandlerMethod existingHandlerMethod = getHandlerMethods().get(mapping);
        if (existingHandlerMethod != null) {
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod = createHandlerMethod(handler, method);
            if (handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(existingHandlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass())) {
                logger.warn(handlerMethod.getBeanType().getSimpleName() + " type (" + handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName() + "->" + handlerMethod.getMethod().getName() +
                        ") registration omitted to avoid ambigious mapping (" + existingHandlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName() + "->" + existingHandlerMethod.getMethod().getName() + ")");
                return;
            }
            unregisterMapping(mapping);
        }
        super.registerHandlerMethod(handler, method, mapping);
    }

}
```

1. Is this correct way to handle this?
2. When I add @EnableWebMvc annotation, this becomes useless. Is there any more generic solution?

Comment: You have duplicated mappings, you cannot map the same URL to different methods, regardless if you override or not. So no this is not the way to handle it. Don't extend the base class and just implement the logic in here.

Comment: @M.Deinum This is small part of the controllers. I've many different methods on base controller. I just want to override one of them with same url.

Comment: You cannot as all of the metadata will be processed leading to the same URL/mapping. It will only work if the mapping differs. Apparently you are adding a different parameter so include that in the mapping information to have a unique mapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @GetMapping({
            PATH_GET,
            PATH_VIEW_GET}
    )
```

is being repeated in both the parent and child class so you are facing the Ambiguous mapping. please change the path for one.

Comment: I'm aware of that they have same mapping. I want RequestMappingHandlerMapping to choose sub-controller's method.